# remote MySQL with java ignores a column

Tags: mysql, jdbc

once again I am forced to seek for an answer here since what happens doesn't make the least sense to me and perhaps you people would know what is going on.

I'm connecting to a remote MySQL server, my problem is that somehow I get a "column doesn't exist" kind of error, let me explain it in detail below.

Right after connecting I check if my database responds correctly to a query, seems it does

```
    st.executeQuery("SET CHARSET latin2"); 
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT NrKarty, IloscWejsc, OdDnia, DoDnia FROM Karta");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(4));

    }
```

I get a result like this (NrKarty is a primary key of this table)

```
5230303030303034443030463644323745
10
2012-12-13
2016-05-12
```

And this result is perfectly fine, all is good etc.
Problem starts when I need to ask for data on a specific record in this table, which is indicated by the primary key (NrKarty).

Naturally, my query looks like this

```
Statement st = conn1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT IloscWejsc, OdDnia, DoDnia FROM Karta WHERE NrKarty='"+cardCode+"'");
```

Card code is written fine. Query is fine too:

```
SELECT IloscWejsc, OdDnia, DoDnia FROM Karta WHERE NrKarty='5230303030303034443030463644323745'
```

I checked the query in phpMyAdmin, returned proper results.

But in java I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NrKarty' in 'where clause'
```

And honestly it makes no sense to me, perhaps someone wiser gets it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking to the same database + schema?

Comment: What about hidden whitespace?

Comment: Any chance of accidentally using homoglyphs (letters from different scripts that look the same)?

Comment: Any chance of negative caching on the Java side?

Comment: Have you check string right connection?

Comment: Same database+schema, don't switch anywhere from it, only 1 connection is set in the program, homoglyphs aren't an issue here. Additionally if I try to receive columns by names, as in System.out.println("NrKarty") I also get the no column message. Perhaps issue is connected to latin2 coding, but how? Every single thing is set in latin2 in DB and connection is set to latin2 too. Don't even know how to check for negative caching but I suppose not, this case seems rly weird.

Comment: How do you know you are getting any rows returned?

Comment: Wait wait wait, I might be those homoglyphs, let me check it out throughtly. Nope, guess that isn't the case :(. System.out.println("NrKarty") works... Perhaps it's an issue with InnoDB or something, seriously, no idea.

Comment: See if you can recreate it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I have this another query in another class which receives passed on Connection object and refers to it, seems that if I put those 2 queries right on start both work correctly, I will now search for possible mistakes, will keep you guys posted. Probably something stupid :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just as I thought, it was simple, dumb and so similar to all the mistakes I do :D, right below that one query I had another one which wasn't correct and it was the one that threw the error while i thought that it's the other one all the time, perhaps if I looked with more care at compilation results, I would have known, sorry guys for that.

Correct query should look like this (in another table, the one that threw the error)

```
SELECT Zajecie_idZajecia FROM KartaZajecie WHERE Karta_NrKarty='5230303030303034443030463644323745'
```